# How to remove portion of url when using NavigateURL

Tags: asp.net, string, navigateurl

I am using NavigateURL to dynamically pull in the url of products on a receipt page.

Here is the exact code:

```
<a class="blue13" href="<%#Eval("Product.NavigateUrl")%>"><%#Eval("Product.Name")%></a>
```

It is placing "/checkout/~/" in each of the url.

How can I remove or correct this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need runat=server in that <a> tag?

Comment: I am not sure, as i am a .net beginner and am walking into this project. But I did plug that in and it did not correct the problem. Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no reason to have runat="server" on that tag. I'd say there is never a good enough reason to have it on any html tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching from a regular href to an asp:HyperLink and it corrected the /~/ issue.

So, before I was using

```
<a class="blue13" href="<%#Eval("Product.NavigateUrl")%>" runat="server"><%#Eval("Product.Name")%></a><br/>
```

And I switched it to:

```
<asp:HyperLink CssClass="blue13" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Product.NavigateUrl")%>' Text='<%#Eval("Product.Name")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Which correct the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would probably be to just call `.Replace()` and replace the unwanted part with a empty string. But it depends relay. Why is it there to begin with? Where is the data coming from?

Comment: Thanks Mattias. I actually just figured out a solution.